# Python: How to print a number pyramid and display the multiples of 3 and 0 in remaining space

Tags: python

In place of integers not divisible by 3, I need 0s.

For example:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

the final output should be:

```
0
0 3
0 0 6
0 0 9 0
```

Comment: I’m afraid you’ve forgotten to post your code attempt at solving this on your own?  What *specific* issue are you facing?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @S3DEV that you should have at least tried it yourself and posted your attempts and described what specific problems you still struggle with.

But since I am not your mother or your teacher and I was intrigued by that exercise, here is my solution:

```py
def render_level(
    start: int,
    stop: int,
    divisor: int = 1,
    number_width: int = 1
) -> str:
    """
    Returns a string of numbers from `start` to `stop - 1` separated by spaces.

    Every number in the range not divisible by `divisor` will be replaced by 0.
    At least `number_width` characters will be reserved for each number.
    """
    return " ".join(
        f"{num if not num % divisor else 0:{number_width}}"
        for num in range(start, stop)
    )


def print_pyramid(num_levels: int, divisor: int = 1) -> None:
    """
    Prints a numbers pyramid with the height `num_levels` to stdout.

    Every number not divisible by `divisor` will be replaced by 0.
    """
    last_num = num_levels * (num_levels + 1) // 2
    number_width = len(str(last_num))
    last_level = render_level(
        last_num - num_levels + 1,
        last_num + 1,
        divisor=divisor,
        number_width=number_width,
    )
    last_level_width = len(last_level)
    start_num = 1
    for i in range(1, num_levels):
        level = render_level(
            start_num,
            start_num + i,
            divisor=divisor,
            number_width=number_width
        )
        indentation = (last_level_width - len(level)) // 2
        print(" " * indentation, level, sep="")
        start_num += i
    print(last_level)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_pyramid(5, 3)
```

This is the output:

```
       0
     0  3
    0  0  6
  0  0  9  0
 0 12  0  0 15
```

You can also call `print_pyramid` with any other divisor instead of `3`. Calling `print_pyramid(6, 2)` will give the following output:

```
        0
       2  0
     4  0  6
    0  8  0 10
  0 12  0 14  0
16  0 18  0 20  0
```

And you can call it without a divisor argument. Then it will print just a regular numbers pyramid. Calling `print_pyramid(9)` will give you:

```
             1
           2  3
          4  5  6
        7  8  9 10
      11 12 13 14 15
    16 17 18 19 20 21
   22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
```

**EDIT:** Had it the other way around with the `0`s. Fixed it now.

Comment: You might wish to simply pass in a predicate that determines which numbers to replace with `0`. More flexible that way.

Answer (score -1):

Although a coding attempt has not been provided, the intent of this answer is not a 'code-drop' but for **educational purposes**, with documentation links provided for each concept.

---

### The full solution:

```
vals = [0 if i % 3 else i for i in range(1, 16)]

j = 0
for i in range(1, 6):
    print(*vals[j:j+i])
    j += i
```

Output:

```
0
0 3
0 0 6
0 0 9 0 
0 12 0 0 15
```

---

### Breaking it down:

This interesting task can be accomplished in two, very simple steps:

1. Define a list of integers which are divisible by three, with non-divisible integers being replaced by zero.
2. Iterate these values and print the triangle.

#### Step 1:

Create a list if values to be used.

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions), a list of integers which are divisible by three can be created:

```
vals = [0 if i % 3 else i for i in range(1, 16)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 15]
```

#### Step 2:

Iterate the values and print the triangle.

**Note:** Although a pyramid is mentioned in the title, a triangle example is provided in the question.

The variables `i` and `j` are used to [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) (or extract) the required values from the list.  The ['splat' operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations) (`*`) is used in the `print` function to expand (or unpack) the list into individual list values for printing.

```
j = 0
for i in range(1, 6):
    print(*vals[j:j+i])
    j += i
```

Comment: Offers a complete suggestion to a question that exhibits no effort. Also, a suggestion: if you use `enumerate` you don't need to increment `j` explicitly.  `for j, i in enumerate(range(1, 6)): print(*vals[j:j+i])`

Comment: You have also put in misleading links. You are using a conditional expression, and not adding a condition to the list comprehension.